# Why am I getting "Operation not permitted for current customer" when trying to create a new conversion action in Google Ads?

Tags: google-ads-api, adsense

I'm trying to [setup conversion tracking in Google Ads](https://support.google.com/google-ads/answer/6095821?hl=en) for a client. When I try to create a new conversion action and hit "create and continue", I get the error message `Operation not permitted for current customer`. What can I do to resolve it? Is it a permissions issue?

Comment: Yes, it is most likely a permissions issue. I don't think anyone here can help with that.